# SQL Job: CmdExec with Multiple Arguments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Is it possible to specify two arguments to CmdExec in SQL JOb Step?

I have MyApp.exe Para1 Para2

but it only recognize para1.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in [sysjobsteps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187387%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to see what SQL Server stores as the command.

If it says "MyApp.exe Para1 Para2" then it means Para2 is probably not recognised by myApp.exe

Comment: in mYApp.exe it only args(1) gives index out of bound errors

it does see args(0) as Para1

This is in .NET console app.  

so: 

1) MyApp.exe is being executed
2) It sees at least the first parameter

Comment: @Vilasack Phothisan: you have no checked what SQL Serve Agent is storing. It may not send the 2nd parameter for example.